# Enable content in CSS Tabs

Tags: html, css

I'm using the code from the following site: http://calebogden.com/css-tabs/ which has allowed me to create some CSS tabs, however, the content is only visible when you hover over one of the tabs and ideally I would like the content to be visible without people having to do that.

The code is:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="content" role="main">

            <div id="tabs">
                <nav class="tabs">
                    <a href="#">About Scamper</a>
                    <section class="tabs-content">
                        Scamper is the coolest.
                    </section>
                    <a href="#">His Anatomy</a>
                    <section class="tabs-content">
                        Partly because he's a penguin.
                    </section>
                    <a href="#">Life Achievements</a>
                    <section class="tabs-content">
                        But also he had a movie made about him.
                    </section>
                    <a href="#">More Info</a>
                    <section class="tabs-content">
                        These tabs sure are great.
                    </section>
                </nav>
            </div>

        </div>

<!-- css -->

#content { padding: 25px; background: #FFF; }

    #tabs {
        border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 205px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .tabs-content {
        padding: 25px;
        height: 120px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    .tabs {
        overflow: hidden; 
        background: #e1e1e1; 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #f2f2f2, #e1e1e1); 
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f2f2f2), color-stop(100%,#e1e1e1)); 
        -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF inset; 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF inset; 
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF inset;
    }
    .tabs a {
        display: block; 
        float: left; 
        font: 15px/35px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; 
        padding: 0 20px 0 40px; 
        color: #999; 
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
        border-left: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        border-right: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .tabs a:first-child {
        border-left-width: 0;
    }
    .tabs a:last-child {
        border-right-width: 0;
    }
    .tabs a:after {
        content: '✔';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 10px;
        line-height: 21px;
        font-size: 10px;
        width: 21px; 
        text-align: center; 
        margin: 7px 10px 5px 0; 
        background: #000; 
        font-size: 12px; 
        -moz-border-radius: 21px; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 21px; 
        border-radius: 21px; 
        background: #bdbdbd; 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #d4d4d4, #bdbdbd); 
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d4d4d4), color-stop(100%,#bdbdbd)); 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset; 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset; 
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset; 
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999; 
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .tabs a:hover {
        background: #FFF;
        border-left-color: #CCC;
    }
    .tabs a:hover:after {
        background: #038bd5; 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #2dc3fc, #038bd5); 
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2dc3fc), color-stop(100%,#038bd5)); 
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #096c9e; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.45), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,148,255,0.85); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.45), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,148,255,0.85); 
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.45), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,148,255,0.85)
    }
    .tabs a:hover + .tabs-content {
        display: block;
    }
    .tabs-content:hover {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Can anyone assist in what I need to edit in the CSS to do this based on the code provided in the script?

Comment: Impossible to help you without you providing the **relevant** code here on SO and perhaps even better also provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You want content to be visible on clicking a tab or ?. If so I don't think that there is a way to do it solely in CSS you should use some javascript and click event.

Comment: @BillJohnson Could you trim it down to only the *relevant* code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an updated version of the code which allows you to click on a tab to view the content. After clicking, the content remains visible.

http://calebogden.com/advanced-css-tabs/

Relevant excerpts:

> Since we are going to be using the target selector, we’ll need to add
>   ID’s [sic] to the links, and selectors the the HREF attributes as well. This
>   will allow us to select the tab via it’s target, and it’s next sibling
>   from the same method. The new HTML for a link will be as follows:
>
> ```
> <a id="tab1" href="#tab1">Scamper</a>
> ```
>
> With the HTML revised, now all we need to do is change the selectors from using :hover to :target.
>
> ```
> .tabs a:target { declarations } 
> .tabs a:target:after { declarations } 
> .tabs a:target + section.tabs-content { declarations }
> ```

Here is a working fiddle showing the `:target` selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/8BKtz/

To select an initial tab, you can put the hash into the URL.

@matthias.p shows a nicer solution for selecting an initial tab by using smarter selectors. However all solutions (including the original code and my solution) rely on newer CSS selectors so they will break partially or completely in IE8 and below, even with a library like Modernizr added to support the HTML 5 elements used (like `section`).

For now, I would probably use a snippet of JavaScript to make the code more widely compatible. It's nice to know that in the future a pure CSS solution will be available.

Here's a complete solution which uses JS to achieve greater compatibility: http://jsfiddle.net/hN4S3/1/

Comment: Hi Tim,Thanks for that and is there a way to ensure that the first tab is visible, without someone needing to first click it? Thanks

Comment: Any chance of you providing me with that Javscript as I would like to stay with the code in place as the tabs look really nice and the only sticking point is the first tab. Thanks

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/8BKtz/8/. I did a few things: added jQuery (you can use plain JS if you want), added Modernizr (need this because you are using HTML 5 elements), and added script that works in IE7/8.

Comment: Note that :target is removed altogether because IE7/8 don't support that either. If you only want IE9+, then you could do something simpler. There are suggestions in the comments on the author's page: http://calebogden.com/advanced-css-tabs/

Comment: Hi, thank you VERY much for that. Strangely the first tab now shows the content; however, when I select tab2 and tab3 etc nothing is happening? I have added the JS and that is contained within the header.

Comment: Did you add a reference to jQuery? It won't work without that (unless you convert the script to generic JS).

Comment: Sorry I'm not following you as new to code....I have added the Javascript you wrote into a file called tab.js and referenced this <script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/js/tabs.js'></script> do I need to download JQuery library and include that also? Thanks again

Comment: Include `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` as well and it should work.

Comment: Added that and gone back through everything that you have provided and ensured that all is present and correct....however, tabs still don't work...any thoughts?

Comment: Just one last question...it would appear that when content is added to each tab and let us say 3 paragraphs, the content then sits outside of the tab area...I see overflow:hidden therefore is there a fix for this as in one tab I'm looking to add 7 paragraphs of text? Thanks

Comment: I changed it up a little to increase the height and use `overflow: auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/hN4S3/2/. Variable height layouts don't seem to be supported by the author's original layout.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/8BKtz/13/ Here's a minimal example without all the frills. I found it useful for learning.

Answer (score 2):

By using the `:target` selector, this is possible. But the problem with all the other answers is, that at first, no tab is selected, but it is usual that the first tab is already selected and that the state that no tab at all is selected, cannot exist. Here is how I do my tab navigations:
http://jsfiddle.net/UejbP/1/
As you can see, the first tab is automatically selected -- without any javascript.

Comment: Nice usage of the `~` selector...on the downside, none of these solutions work in IE8 or below because of the newer selectors.

Comment: @TimMedora Another disadvantage of my solution is that you have to place the tabs in reverse order in the html file, because `~` can only match elements after something, but there is not yet a selector to get all elements before something. And furthermore, all of the solutions using the `:target` selector don't work if you want to include more than one tab panel, because if you switch in one tab panel to another tab, the selection of the other tab panel will get lost. So maybe it is still the best to do tabs simply with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
.tabs-content {
    padding: 25px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none; //REMOVE THIS LINE
}
```

If you want the content to be visible at all times which it sounds like you want it to do, then only remove that line and you will be all fine :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would make *all* the tabs visible all the time.

Comment: Kills the tabs altogether when I apply that and the content contained within the first tab is then the same for all tabs. Shame as that would have been an easy fix!

Comment: Yes it will @TimMedora, but that's what he asked for in his post.